# VBA Delete Border around Range

Tags: excel, vba

I need to clear the old range border before applying the new one with the change, I've been trying with no success. It should be done before the `'Set New Duration` in holding cell.

How can I achieve this?

```
If Cells(9, Target.Column).Value = "Dur" Then 'Duration Change and Check for proper database column
                
                'Update Colors
                
                'Clears Old Color
                
                If Range("A8").Value <> Empty Then Range(Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column), Cells(Target.Row + Range("A8").Value - 1, Target.Column + 3)).Interior.Color = 16777215 'Clear Previous Colors Based on Previous Duration (if any)
                             
                'Set New Duration in holding cell
                Range("A7").Value = Target.Value
                
                'Sets New color
                If Target.Value <> Empty Then Range(Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column), Cells(Target.Row + Range("A8").Value - 1, Target.Column + 3)).Interior.Color = Range("FillColor").Interior.Color  'Add New Color
                
                'Sets Border around
                If Target.Value <> Empty Then Range(Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column), Cells(Target.Row + Range("A8").Value - 1, Target.Column + 3)).BorderAround , ColorIndex:=xlAutomatic, Weight:=xlThin

End If
```

Answer (score 1):

This will remove all borders from range `A1`.

```
With Range("A1")
    .Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
End With
```

*<sup>Source: Macro Recorder. According to GSerg's comment and the documentation it would be better to replace `xlNone` with `xlLineStyleNone` (numerically they are the same `-4142` so both would work).</sup>*

Although the documentation of the [Range.BorderAround method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.borderaround) says:

> To clear the border, you must set the `LineStyle` property to `xlLineStyleNone` for all the cells in the range.

it happens that obviously due to a bug `Range("A1").BorderAround LineStyle:=xlLineStyleNone` does not work. So you would have to do it with the first code block.

Comment: `xlNone` happens to be numerically equal to `xlLineStyleNone`, but it's the latter that should be used.

Comment: @GSerg Actually the macro recorder produces code with `xlNone` but you are right, the documentation of the [XlLineStyle enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xllinestyle) tells it should be `xlLineStyleNone`. Obviously Microsoft isn't very consistent here themeselves.

Comment: Strange, it didn't work for me on office16. First, I tried `xlLineStyleNone`. It didn't remove the borders. Then, I tried `-4118`. It turned continuous line into a dotted one. Then, `Range("B2:D2").Borders.LineStyle = xlNone` removed the border.